# Null Value in Database causing undefined index using PHP and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I have data that was imported from our mainframe and the last column in the table has null values.  (varchar, allow nulls checked. obv.)  The field name is all in caps (a result of the mainframe data dump... this is an important clue).  When I try to retrieve and echo the data from that field, I get an "UNDEFINED INDEX" error if the field value is Null.  If the field has data, I'm fine.

**HOWEVER:** if i rename the field to something with a lower case letter at the beginning, it works fine, nulls or not.

**NOTE:** if i put a number at the beginning of the field it doesn't work either.

Trying to find a way around this since I'm dealing with a LOT of tables that are going to get dumped and re-created on an almost daily basis from these mainframe extracts, id rather not have to change the field names.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

EDIT: I tried to use "isset" but you cannot check isset on a `$XXX->fields('fieldname')` line of code.  Tried using `if(!($XXX->fields('fieldname'))` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of your ability to use `isset()`, you can compare if it is *exactly* NULL with three equals signs ([identical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)):

```
if ( $XXX->fields('fieldname') === NULL ) { 
    // NULL value, do something else...
} else {
    // Not NULL, try something...
}
```

That doesn't solve your undefined index problem, however. Did you write the class that produces `->fields('fieldname')`? If so, or even if not, you can modify the class function `fields()` to check `isset()` there and return NULL if not set, or the value if set.

Based on your code in the comments, you might try replacing:

`return $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]];`

with:

`return ( isset( $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]] ) ? $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]] : NULL );`

This checks if `$this->fields[ ... ]` is set, and if so, returns it, and if not, returns null.

But, if that doesn't work, try replacing the same with:

`return ( isset( $this->bind[strtoupper($colname)] ) ? $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]] : NULL );`

This checks if `$this->bind[ ... ]` is set, and if so, returns it, and if not, returns null.

Comment: You're on to something here.  The code for "fields" function:
`if (!$this->bind) {
    $this->bind = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $this->_numOfFields; $i++) {
     $o = $this->FetchField($i);
     $this->bind[strtoupper($o->name)] = $i;
    }
   }
   return $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]];`

the strtoupper could be the issue here.  Would it be safe to remove that translation?

Comment: I think we *might* need to go one level deeper to `FetchField()`. But, why don't you try replacing `return $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]];` with: `return ( isset( $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]] ) ? $this->fields[$this->bind[strtoupper($colname)]] : NULL );`

Comment: have put two code blocks to try into the answer itself so it's easier to read

Comment: Was just going to add the fetchfield bit in my comment, but yes that was it!  It was first going to strtolower then strtoupper and something was getting gummed up there.  I removed the case modifiers and it works now.  Thanks so much! :)